# Error displaying oEmbed Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I've a problem with my wordpress website. When I insert some url for being embedded, it's not working fine.

Here is the issue URL : https://www.duosia.id/windows/cara-mengekstrak-files-menggunakan-winrar-dengan-mudah

And here is the Screenshot :

[image]

When I try to visit the embedded url. It's return 404 not found. You can check the embedded url here, https://www.duosia.id/windows/cara-mengekstrak-files-menggunakan-winrar-dengan-mudah/embed/

I've try these common solutions.

1. Update everything including WordPress, the theme and plugins. Available updates appear in Dashboard > Updates.
2. Deactivate all plugins in case there is a conflict. If the problem goes away while all plugins are inactive, then reactivate them one by one to determine which is causing the problem.
3. Switch to the default theme (such as Twenty Thirteen) then try to do what was not working. If the problem remains, it is a general WordPress or hosting issue. If it happens only while using our theme, please let us know.
4. Clear cache in both your browser and in any caching plugins that you are using (also disable services like CloudFlare, if used with your website).
5. Revert code changes if you have modified the theme’s code. If using a child theme, reactivate the parent theme.

But, seems no one work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WordPress post embeds don't seem to be working on your site.
This URL shows a live example of the problem:

https://www.duosia.id/windows/whatsapp-for-pc/

The two embeds present in that URL are returning a 404, therefore, oEmbeds are not loading properly and showing the 404 page:

https://www.duosia.id/windows/facebook-messenger-for-pc/embed/#?secret=kMPv636bx1
https://www.duosia.id/windows/line-for-pc/embed/#?secret=65m4VpxiYi

Have you tried testing those URLs in the plugin "Rewrite Rules Inspector"?
You should see [something like this](https://i.imgur.com/njhCBMU.png) for any of the "embed" URLs:

```
index.php?name=$matches[1]&embed=true
```

Also, have you tried flushing the rewrite rules in WordPress or maybe setting the permalink structure to a different/default one (right now you seem to be using a structure of "category/post-name") to see if it changes anything?

Comment: when i try to search "index.php?name=$matches[1]&embed=true" embed rewrite rule with plugin "Rewrite Rules Inspector", the result is not found.

Comment: You should input one of the "embed" URLs in the Rewrite Rules plugin: https://www.duosia.id/windows/line-for-pc/embed/#?secret=65m4VpxiYi Then see if it returns any results (like the ones I showed here https://i.imgur.com/njhCBMU.png)

Comment: Also, have you tried any of the things I told you in the last paragraph?

Comment: no result for "embed" URLs in the Rewrite Rules plugin

Comment: In that case I would say there is something in the theme/plugins that is disabling this functionality. Shouldn't be the case as you said in the original post you tried disabling all plugins and themes.

Comment: Thank you! I checked twice and it caused by wp rocket 

Answer (score 0):

For the file that you are embedding, are you uploading it to the Media Library or some other plugin?

First I would check on the server to verify that the file you are looking to access does exist.

Once you know that the file does exist, then repeat the steps you have listed again.

Comment: I'm ont embedding file, just url which is it'll automatically converted to iframe by oEmbed Wordpress.